# HTML- Content not displayed properly in tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I am very new to front end development and stuck while working with tabs in HTML. I am trying to display content in tabs and somehow I an able to do it but it only works if any of the tab button is pressed. The entire content shows up as the page loads and eventually as the tab buttons are clicked, it works fine.

Can somebody please correct me?

https://jsfiddle.net/pndmyaf7/

CSS

```
    .tab {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
    .tab button {
        background-color: inherit;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    .tab button.active {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.tab-content>.active {
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML

```
<fieldset class="tab" style="margin-top: 150px ";>


<legend align="center">Exposure Breakdown</legend>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'exposure_by_asset_type')">Asset Class</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'exposure_by_leh_sector')">LEH Sector</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'exposure_by_gics_sector')">GICS Sector</button>
</fieldset>

<div id="exposure_by_asset_type" class="tab-content">
    <h3>Test0</h3>
</div>

<div id="exposure_by_leh_sector" class="tab-content">
            <h3>Tes1</h3>
</div>

<div id="exposure_by_gics_sector" class="tab-content">
            <h3>Test2</h3>
</div>
```

JS

```
function openTab(evt, chart_id) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-content");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(chart_id).style.display = "block";
    evt.cur`enter code here`rentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility of the content initially to none. You can simply add this to your css file:

```
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Actually, I am trying to display google charts in the tabs and setting the display attribute of tab-contents to none. just messes up the charts. Take a look @ https://jsfiddle.net/fbs5daot/